# How to get the document(page) left and top along with its scroll(scroll left and top) relative to the body?

Tags: javascript

- I want to get onclick of page position(x and y) along with scroll values if the page got any scrolls
- And also want the below jquery code as javascript code:

  ```
   $("#drag").mouseup(function(event){
  var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;         
  $("#pos").html(x + ', ' + y);    });
  ```

```
<div id="drag" style="width:2000px;height:2000px;border:1px solid #000; top:100px;               left:100px; position:absolute; background-color: #AACCEE">
</div>
```

Comment: The code ***is*** in JavaScript.

Comment: "$" refers to jquery rite??

Comment: is these a question here or is this a riddle?

Comment: @Rachel Do you mean to convert the jQuery.offset()? If yes you can open the jQuery source and get the implementation of this function.

Comment: Are you trying to achive the same results without a dependancy for jQuery?

Comment: You could look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.offsetTop

Comment: You may want to edit, and ask to how to do this without jQuery. jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: i want the same results without a dependancy of jQuery..

Comment: thanks for the comments, answer and for the down vote..

Comment: To be fair, you actually haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

*Discalimer: Not sure about IE*

```
document.getElementById('drag').onmouseup = function(event){
    var event = event || window.event;
    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;         
    document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = x + ', ' + y;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bn3TQ/)